# Getting Error : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm new to spring and spring boot application. Getting the error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource. It says unable to build EntityManagerFactory. Error is displayed in console:

```
2018-08-01 17:47:38.920[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m19412[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity.FuseTPS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.telenor.wipro.logging.logserviceapp.LoggerServiceApplication.main(LoggerServiceApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity.FuseTPS
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:731) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

My Application Starting Point: **LoggerServiceApplication.java**

```
package com.telenor.wipro.logging.logserviceapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.telenor.wipro.logging.*")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebMvc
public class LoggerServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoggerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My controller class: **LoggingServiceWebController.java**

```
package com.telenor.wipro.logging.controller;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.telenor.wipro.logging.dto.Search;
import com.telenor.wipro.logging.dto.SearchTPS;
import com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity.FuseTPS;
import com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.repository.FuseLogsRepository;
import com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.repository.FuseTpsRepository;
import com.telenor.wipro.logging.service.LoggerService;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
// This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class LoggingServiceWebController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingServiceWebController.class);

    @Value("${welcome.message}")
    private String message; 

    @Autowired
    LoggerService loggerService;

    @Autowired
    FuseLogsRepository fuseLogsRepository;

    @Autowired
    FuseTpsRepository fuseTpsRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {

        LOGGER.debug("Welcome {}", "testing");
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchFuseLogs(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("search", new Search());
        return "search";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getFuseLogs(Model model, @ModelAttribute Search search) {

        String strFromDate = "";
        String strToDate = "";

        if(search.fdate != null && !search.fdate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            strFromDate = search.fdate;
        } else {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30);
            strFromDate = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime());
        }

        strFromDate = strFromDate + " 00:00:00,000";
        System.out.println(strFromDate);
        Date dtFromDate = new Date();
        try {
            dtFromDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS").parse(strFromDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Timestamp tsFromDate = new Timestamp(dtFromDate.getTime());


        if(search.tdate != null && !search.tdate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            strToDate = search.tdate;
        } else {
            strToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        }

        strToDate = strToDate + " 23:59:59,999";
        System.out.println(strToDate);
        Date dtToDate = new Date();
        try {
            dtToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS").parse(strToDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Timestamp tsToDate = new Timestamp(dtToDate.getTime());

        System.out.println("From Date: "+tsFromDate);
        System.out.println("To Date: "+tsToDate);

        model.addAttribute("fuseLogs", fuseLogsRepository.findByAll(
                tsFromDate, 
                tsToDate,
                search.tpayload.toUpperCase(),
                search.tguid.toUpperCase(), 
                search.tservicename.toUpperCase(), 
                search.tsourcechannel.toUpperCase(), 
                search.ttargetsystem.toUpperCase()));

        return "show";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/SearchTPS", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchTPS(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("SearchTPS", new SearchTPS());
        return "SearchTPS";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/SearchTPS", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getTPS(Model model, @ModelAttribute SearchTPS searchtps) {
        System.out.println("Service Name"+searchtps.tservicename);

        model.addAttribute("tpslist", fuseTpsRepository.findByTPS());
        return "ShowTPS";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public String getAllLogs(Model model) {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        model.addAttribute("fuseLogs",fuseLogsRepository.findAll());
        return "all";
    }

}
```

My Entity Class: **FuseTPS.java**

```
package com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity;

import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table(name="fuse_logs")
public class FuseTPS {

    String countTPS;
    String serviceName;

    public String getCountTPS() {
        return countTPS;
    }
    public void setCountTPS(String countTPS) {
        this.countTPS = countTPS;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }
}
```

My Entity Class: **FuseLogs.java**

```
package com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name="fuse_logs")
public class FuseLogs {

    @Column(name = "log_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;

    @Column(name = "log_timestamp")
    Timestamp logTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "log_level")
    String logLevel;

    @Column(name = "thread_id")
    String threadID;

    @Column(name = "stage")
    String stage;

    @Column(name = "componant_id")
    String componantID;

    @Column(name = "logpoint")
    String logpoint;

    @Column(name = "gu_id")
    String guID;

    @Column(name = "source_cahnnel")
    String sourceCahnnel;

    @Column(name = "target_system")
    String targetSystem;

    @Column(name = "service_name")
    String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "free_text")
    String freeText;

    @Column(name = "container_name")
    String containerName;

    @Column(name = "payload")
    String payload;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getLogTimeStamp() {
        return logTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setLogTimeStamp(Timestamp logTimeStamp) {
        this.logTimeStamp = logTimeStamp;
    }

    public String getLogLevel() {
        return logLevel;
    }

    public void setLogLevel(String logLevel) {
        this.logLevel = logLevel;
    }

    public String getThreadID() {
        return threadID;
    }

    public void setThreadID(String threadID) {
        this.threadID = threadID;
    }

    public String getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    public void setStage(String stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public String getComponantID() {
        return componantID;
    }

    public void setComponantID(String componantID) {
        this.componantID = componantID;
    }

    public String getLogpoint() {
        return logpoint;
    }

    public void setLogpoint(String logpoint) {
        this.logpoint = logpoint;
    }

    public String getGuID() {
        return guID;
    }

    public void setGuID(String guID) {
        this.guID = guID;
    }

    public String getSourceCahnnel() {
        return sourceCahnnel;
    }

    public void setSourceCahnnel(String sourceCahnnel) {
        this.sourceCahnnel = sourceCahnnel;
    }

    public String getTargetSystem() {
        return targetSystem;
    }

    public void setTargetSystem(String targetSystem) {
        this.targetSystem = targetSystem;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    public String getFreeText() {
        return freeText;
    }

    public void setFreeText(String freeText) {
        this.freeText = freeText;
    }

    public String getContainerName() {
        return containerName;
    }

    public void setContainerName(String containerName) {
        this.containerName = containerName;
    }

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

}
```

My repository interface: **FuseTpsRepository.java**
I want to access total count group by service name as described in query from a table fuse_logs which is already created by spring above FuseLogs.java

```
package com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity.FuseTPS;

@Repository
public interface FuseTpsRepository {

    @Query(value="SELECT COUNT(distinct gu_id), service_name FROM fuse_logs WHERE GROUP BY service_name",nativeQuery=true)
    public List<FuseTPS> findByTPS();
}
```

**application.yml**

```
welcome:
  message: Hello 

#For local System
logger-filepath: E:\\JBossEAP\\fuse-logs\\fuse.log


server:
  port: 9092
  context-path: /logger-service

spring:
  datasource:
#    For local System
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?currentSchema=public
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: DB@123

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true 
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.telenor.wipro.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoggingService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>LoggingService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Postgress Java Connector library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My template body: **ShowTPS.html**

```
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>About 77,200 results (0.64 seconds)</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial No.</th>
            <th>TPS</th>
            <th>Service Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="list,iterationStatus  : ${tpslist}">
            <td th:text="${iterationStatus.count}"></td>
            <td th:text="${list.countTPS}"></td>
            <td th:text="${list.serviceName}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
    <!-- <a href="/search">Search Again</a> -->
</body>
```

I want to access the total count group by service_name from fuse_logs table and show it to ShowTPS.html template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is
No identifier specified for entity: com.telenor.wipro.logging.jpa.entity.FuseTPS

This class is really confusing. It has no @Entity annotation, no @Id, and references the same table as FuseLogs. You need to fix this class. Add all the proper annotations and correct the table.